# Linq to SQL and MySQL database

Tags: mysql, linq-to-sql

Is it possible to use all features of Linq to SQL for a MySQL database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Linq to Sql is specific to SQL Server. Consider using Linq to Entities or NHibernate.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/linqprojectgeneral/thread/2e6ca49a-4a27-443f-98f3-71c79b74bdd1/